# Converting AES encrpytion python class to C#

Tags: c#, python, encryption, aes

I am converting an API class in python to C# for a Unity school project. The line I am confused on is:

```
return self.encoder.decode(AES.new(base64.b64decode(key), AES.MODE_CBC, '\x00'*16).decrypt(base64.b64decode(input)))
```

I have already implemented `self.encoder.decode`, But I have not found an alternative for the AES class.
I am using the following function for `base64.b64decode(key)`:

```
private static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
     var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
     return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Documentation for the AES module can be found here: https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Would you like help finding a module in C# to perform crypto tasks using AES? If so, there is already one built into the core library, you can call it using `using System.Security.Cryptography`; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data

Comment: I know of the Cryptography class, but I am unsure how to use it in the way the python script describes. Currently the way I am doing it is about 30 lines and does not produce the same output.

Comment: Your Python code does the following: 1)Base64 decodes a key (string). 2)Initiates an AES object with args: the key (bytes), `MODE_CBC` (int with value 2 - it means use CBC mode) and an IV (bytes with value 16 zeros).  3)Base64 decodes the input data (string). 4)Uses the AES object to decrypt that data (bytes). 5)Passes the result to a `self.encoder.decode()` method. In `Base64Decode` you're converting the key to string. That's wrong, it should return bytes. Use .NET's [AES](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8) class for decryption.